# How can I simulate a tap/swipe gesture on some part of the screen programmatically in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swipe, gesture, tinder

I have a SwiftUI app that behaves similarly to Tinder ([built using this guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-create-a-tinder-style-swipeable-card-view-283e257cb102) - or see [source code](https://github.com/bbaars/SwiftUI-Tinder-SwipeableCards)). You just swipe a stack of cards left and right. I have a "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" button as alternatives to swiping, but when they are pressed, I'd like it to swipe the card away *for* the user as if they had swiped it themselves.

Are there any ways to do this in SwiftUI without UIKit?

Comment: Could you post your code for context? Linked article requires membership.

Comment: @Dmitriy sure thing, added a link to the repo.

Answer (score 3):

If your thumbs up and down buttons were part of the `CardView` then it would be quite simple to achieve: just repeat whatever code executes on gesture inside a button action. Something along these lines:

```
                   // CardView.swift

                   Button (action: {
                        // hardcoded for simplicity
                        self.translation = .init(width: 100, height: 0)
                        self.swipeStatus = .like
                        // a hacky way to "wait" for animation to complete
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3, execute: {
                            self.onRemove(self.user)
                        })
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
```

But, if your buttons reside outside of the `CardView`, I think you'll have to re-architect your views a little bit. I would start by converting `swipeStatus` from `@State` into a `@Binding`, so its value can be passed down from the parent view. Then you will need to declare a state variable in your `ContentView`, which you can then tie together with `swipeStatus` binding. Something like:

```
                                    // ContentView.swift

                                    @State var currentSwipeStatus: LikeDislike = .none
                                    ....
                                    CardView(
                                        swipeStatus: self.users.last == user
                                        ? $currentSwipeStatus
                                        : .constant(.none),
                                         user: user,
                                         onRemove: { removedUser in
                                        self.users.removeAll { $0.id == removedUser.id}
                                        self.swipeStatus = .none
                                    })
```

Within your card view you'll need to react to the bound value changing. I just appended `onChange` to the main `VStack`:

```
.onChange(of: swipeStatus) { newState in
                if newState == .like {
                        self.translation = .init(width: 100, height: 0)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3, execute: {
                            self.onRemove(self.user)
                        })
                }
            }
```

I feel like there's a more elegant way of achieving this. I'm not a big fan of the `onRemove` callback, `asyncAfter` hack, and the fact that they render all cards at once.
But at least that's a  start.